# OpenGL Android Plotting a real time graph

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, linegraph

Can any one Point me in Best way to plot a real time graph using OpenGL with some exampels

Comment: This shouldn't be very difficult by following any OpenGL ES tutorials available out there. All you have to do is take an example that draws e.g a triangle and use ``GL_LINE_STRIP`` for ``glDrawArrays`` or ``glDrawElements`` command. Once you have lines rendered you can start pointing them to correct positions.

Comment: Dude i tried that the OPENGL crashes for me without any stack trace or exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See..

- http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html
- [Dynamic Graph Plotting with openGL in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235326/dynamic-graph-plotting-with-opengl-in-android)

Comment: I have gone thru all those tutorials not even one explains perfectly how to draw a line.