# How to create ECG animation on Android Application

Tags: android, animation

I coded an android application which is measuring heart rate from camera input. I needed to desing an ECG animation to the application. I know that ECG isn't related. But I'll try to show the sign according to heart rate. Which method do I need to use? Drawing animation into a View object from layout or Drawing graphics directly to a Canvas. And if you give some clues I'll be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To do real time graphing of ECG data...which is what I am coding right now, you need to  create a custom view.   Then in the onDraw method you use your canvas to draw a bitmap.  Then inside the custom I also implement a Runnable that paints the line using drawline, and then invalidates().  I'd show you code but its proprietary since everything I found did not measure up to the speeds I had to graph.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how real-time you need your data.  If a lower framerate is sufficient, then I would recommended subclassing the `View` class and overriding the `onDraw` method.  From there you can draw directly onto the canvas.  Just make sure to call `invalidate` on the view after your data changes to make sure `onDraw` gets called.

If a faster framerate is required, then you probably want to use a `SurfaceView`.  Google has a Lunar Lander example that does a good job of that.  But note some bugs have been found in the example, so use it as a guide not as law.

Lunar Lander:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html